# Home directory reset, all data lost after restart

Tags: zfs, data-loss, data-corruption

After starting my ubuntu 21.10 machine this morning, I find that the home directory of one of my user accounts is completely reset to the state of a new user. All my files are gone and ubuntu presents me with the welcome/setup assistants, as if I were logging in for the first time.

My second, much less used, user account doesn't show any issues.

The system uses a ZFS formatted, encrypted volume. Changing to an old snapshot (system+user data) via the "History" menu in the boot menu does not fix the issue. The home directory is still empty, with only the default "Documents", ... directories (which are also empty).

Running `zpool status` tells me that there are "No known data errors".

I do not remember doing anything special before turning the computer off yesterday. Maybe ubuntu installed a couple of updates, but that's it.

I am really puzzled by this, especially since going to a different ZFS snapshot doesn't seem to help. Could this be triggered by a hardware issue?

Any idea on how to investigate the issue and potentially recover the data would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which specific version are we talking about? In the terminal, the command `lsb_release -a` will provide that info. Add it to the question - use "edit".

Comment: @vanadium `lsb_release -a` doesn't give me any more specific info, only "Ubuntu" as "Distributor ID" and "Ubuntu 21.10" as Description. Codename "impish", but I think that already follows from the version in my original post?

Comment: Sorry, you are right indeed - it was already there in the very beginning.